# trying to convert a regular list view into a clickable list view

Tags: java, android, listview

I started this program by reading in a premade database and has it display on a list, i am currently trying to convert the list to a clickable list that opens up to a new fragment. This is the code i am currently running. The commented out section is the current problem.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button b1 =(Button) findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
        db = new MyDatabase(this);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                schedule = db.getSchedule();
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                //listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this, 
                        R.layout.row,  
                        schedule,                   
                        new String[] {"fName", "Calories", "Protein", "Carbs" },  
                        new int[] { R.id.textView1,  R.id.textView2,  R.id.textView3,  R.id.textView4 },   
                        0));
                schedule = db.getSchedule();
                ListView listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
                listView2.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                        MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.row,
                        schedule,
                        new String[] {"fName", "Calories", "Protein", "Carbs" },
                        new int[] { R.id.textView1,  R.id.textView2,  R.id.textView3,  R.id.textView4 },
                        0));
            }
        });
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);
        // Then you start a new Activity via Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("position", position);
        // Or / And
        intent.putExtra("id", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

listView.setOnItemClickListener(this); will not work because it is being applied to android.view.View.OnClickListener. I have been trying to modify b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(), to try to change its parameters, but I'm not getting any luck. Is there an easy solution I'm not seeing or do i need to reconstruct this code to revolve around a clickable list. Thanks!

Comment: Use `MainActivity.this` as your listener so that `this` isn't referencing your click listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple, put below code lines in `onCreate()` of Activity instead of button's `onClick()` And then implement `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` to your Activity.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Now on line `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);` **this** refers to your activity class and implemented interface and `onItemClick` will work.

If your activity is a `ListActivity` then no need of `listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);` this line.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Activity to ListActivity and override the method onListItemClick of ListActivity class. Put all the code in the onItemClick of listener to 
onListItemClick.